# Upload an html document to Google Docs in python

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I would like to create a small poc module in python 2.7 where I can upload a small html file in google docs and where we can convert it to google document and keep the html in the same stylesheet.

This is an example of my file I would like to upload and convert in google document format.

```
<html> 
 <h1>Heading 1</h1> 
 <h2>Heading 2</h2> 
 <h3>Heading 3</h3> 
 <p>Here we are </p>  
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It would help if you included some code to show what you have tried, it'll make it much easier for us to help you. Perhaps you could also take a look at http://whathaveyoutried.com for a great article on how to ask good questions?

Answer (score -1):

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert#examples

and

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/